# Undefined variable - how to check if var exists

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, undefined

I have 2 type of views that I'll be showing the users: the login page and all the other pages where you'll be able to see a menu.
If you aren't logged in, you won't be seeing the menu.

What I trying to achieve now is use 1 template where the header and the footer is loaded automatically and the content is dynamic depending on which controller called the view.

At the moment I have this in my **login controller**

```
$data['content'] = 'login_view';
$data['menu'] = 'nomenu';
$this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
```

and this is what I have in my **Logged in controllers**

```
$data['content'] = 'profile_view';
$this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
```

Like you can see I won't be sending `$data['menu']`

and my **view** is like so:

```
<?php $this->load->view('templates/header'); ?>
<?php 
    if($menu == 'nomenu'){

    }   
    else{
        $this->load->view($menu);
    }
?>
<?php $this->load->view($content); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('templates/footer'); ?>
```

The problem here is that my logged in controller

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: menu

Filename: templates/template.php

Line Number: 7
```

Is there a way to check if my $menu exists because I'll only be sending $menu if it is the login view, else I wont.

Comment: Don't check if a variable is "undefined". Just ensure that it *can't be* - use an appropriate default/sentinel as required to make sure that it is "defined". This creates cleaner code in the end. Consider that many programming languages prohibit using an "undefined" variable and consider it an *error* in the code that tries to do so.

Comment: I know that is a possible solution, but then I'll always have to send `data[menu]` in every controller, but I only want to send it when it comes from the login controller

Comment: That's what I would do! Don't use "undefined" variables! On the other hand, I find it OK to use map collections with optional keys.

Comment: I don't think that's a very good way to program :) You need to write efficient code that's why I'm asking it here to hope to learn something new :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple just use the `isset` to check that variable is defined or not

```
<?php $this->load->view('templates/header'); ?>
<?php 
    if(isset($menu) && $menu== 'nomenu'){

    }   
    else{
        $this->load->view($menu);
    }
?>
<?php $this->load->view($content); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('templates/footer'); ?>
```

> you probably put the `load` in your if check because if $menu is not set then in else case it will fire the undefined error you should do it like this

```
<?php $this->load->view('templates/header'); ?>
<?php 
    if(isset($menu) && $menu== 'nomenu'){
   $this->load->view($menu);
    }   
    else{
        $this->load->view('load other view');
    }
?>
<?php $this->load->view($content); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('templates/footer'); ?>
```

Comment: This still gives me `Undefined variable: menu`

Answer (score 0):

Or send $data['menu'] = FALSE ; on the 2nd controller

Comment: Can't do that, because later there will be more controllers, and then I'll have to add that in every controller